# Moving sprites in cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have  6 sprites that I want to move around:

-(id) init
{

```
if( (self=[super init]) )
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite * backGround = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background_ipad.png"];
    backGround.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:backGround z:0];

    cloth1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_1.png"];
    cloth1.position = ccp(-200, -15);
    [self addChild:cloth1 z:1];
    cloth2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_2.png"];
    cloth2.position = ccp(130, 225);
    [self addChild:cloth2 z:2];

    cloth3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_3.png"];
    cloth3.position = ccp(365, 225);
    [self addChild:cloth3 z:3];

    cloth4 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_4.png"];
    cloth4.position = ccp(-110, -15);
    [self addChild:cloth4 z:4];

    cloth5 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_5.png"];
    cloth5.position = ccp(130, -20);
    [self addChild:cloth5 z:5];

    cloth6 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clothe_6.png"];
    cloth6.position = ccp(365, -15);
    [self addChild:cloth6 z:6];

}
return self;
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

}

and this method to move:

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
    //Sprite follows the finger movement.
    [cloth1 setPosition:location];
}
```

and the thing is that, I want to add more sprites there to move the sprite. I triend adding more sprites in the //follow the finger movement but then all sprites follow the finger movement. I want to move one single sprite. For example: when touching cloth1, move cloth 1; when touching cloth2, move cloth 2; but not both at the same time.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You deleted your question and posted an almost identical one. Why didn't you just edit it?

Comment: Sorry, because I thought It would be better to do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray  *mSpriteArray;
    CCSprite  *mSpriteOnHand;
}
```

//In implementation:

```
-(id) init 
{
  .. //your old code
  ..

   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth1];
   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth2];
   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth3];
   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth4];
   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth5];
   [mSpriteArray addObject: cloth6];

}

-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    self.touchEnabled = YES; //    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

}


- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    mSpriteOnHand = nil;

    for(CCSprite *cloth in mSpriteArray)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([cloth boundingBox], location))
        {
            mSpriteOnHand = cloth;
            break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if(mSpriteOnHand)
       mSpriteOnHand.position = location;

 }

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    mSpriteOnHand = nil;
}

-(void)onExit
{
   [mSpriteArray release]; 
   mSpriteArray = nil;
   [super onExit];
}
```

Comment: In the ccTouchesEnded, appears an error telling me: Assingning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') from incompatible type 'void*'

Comment: mSpriteOnHand = nil, sorry for mistake.

Comment: Please, no problem at all! I run it and an error appear:
Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer ccTouchBegan:withEvent:], /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/libs/cocos2d/CCLayer.m:280
2013-02-21 15:39:25.520 xxxxxxx [4069:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layer#ccTouchBegan override me'

any idea?

Comment: I dont use CCTouchDispatcher code in init method. remove that CCTouchDispatcher line in init and try.

Comment: Now it runs, but doesnt move any sprite. Don't know what happen.

Comment: hmm..check out my code in onEnter method, self.touchEnabled = YES; //    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

Comment: I'm using the self.isTouchEnabled = YES; the other tells me that "property 'touchEnabled' not found on object of type 'helloworldlayer*' did you mean isTouchEnabled?"

Comment: in Cocos2d new version its touchEnabled and old isTouchEnabled. After adding self.isTouchEnabled you got touch event right?

Comment: Im using "    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;" and no, my sprites don't move at all...

Comment: put printf or break point in ccTouchesBegan method. If not control comes then its some other problem. You can post it in new question. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement always terminates function and returns control to the calling function. You wrote:

```
 return self;
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

`[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher]...` line will never get executed.

Is your class a subclass of `CCLayer`?  If you set layer's `isTouchEnabled` property to `YES`, it will add this layer as standard (non-targeted) touch delegate.

If you must use targeted touch in your layer, you should return `YES` in `-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` if you are claiming this touch, and `NO` if you aren't. Updates of a claimed touch are sent only to the delegate which claimed it.

To determine which sprite is touched: make an instance variable to store "selected" sprite, in `touchBegan` method check which sprite's bounding box contains touch location and store this sprite in instance variable (also, looks like you want to claim a touch only if it's touching a sprite).

```
[cloth1 setPosition:location];
```

-- your sprite will "jump" to touch position. Usually it doesn't look nice. I would get touch's `locationInView:` and `previousLocationInView:`, convert them to GL, get the difference and change sprite's position by that difference.

Comment: Can you please put the methods and specify more what to replace? I'm new in iOS and in Cocos2D...

Comment: Oh. So this is a "give me a fish" kind of question, posted just to get other people to write your code for you.